# Removing first character from a string in octave

Tags: string, matlab, octave

I wanted to know how to remove first character of a string in octave. I am manipulating the string in a loop and after every loop, I want to remove the first character of the remaining string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a one-line string then:

```
short_string = long_string(2:end)
```

But if you have a cell array of strings then either do it as above if you have a loop already, otherwise you can use this shorthand to do it in one line:

```
short_strings = cellfun(@(x)(x(2:end)), long_strings, 'uni', false)
```

Or else if you have a matrix of strings (i.e. all the same length), then you can vectorize it as:

```
short_strings = long_strings(:, 2:end)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you clarify on long string and short string. My string can be 500 characters long.

Comment: @newuser those are just variable names I chose. replace `long_string` with the name of your actual string, and `short_string` with the name of the variable that you want to store the string without its first letter in (this can be the same name if you want to overwrite the variable)

Comment: @Dan which one of the two methods is fastest in execution time?

Comment: @gciriani The best way to answer that is for you to try each method and time them yourself. However, I can say with almost certainty that the third method will be the fastest, however it requires all your strings to be the same length.